# Adding small notes to tables and fields in databases

Tags: mysql, sybase, database-schema

I am working on a project and creating the datamodel. With time and requests, the datamodel is getting bigger, with lot of foreign keys and lot's of columns in few tables wih specific meaning associated with them.

I would like to know, if it is possible that **we could add notes/small text with the table creation to the tables/fields**, so that I could easily store the helpful info in the db itself. So that it can go with the exports and imports I do, to keep backups and other reasons.

Also, this could help other developers, to get small information handy and would reduce the learning curve.

I do favor a full-fledged documentation for the project, which is an indispensable part, but this kind of feature would be helpful.

Please let me know, if this already exists in Mysql/Sybase and in any other db if possible.

Comment: which client/frontend are you using?

Comment: I didn't get exactly your question. Fyi.. I use phpmyadmin for the db and the project front-end is php. But this question is totally dependent on database side and has nothing to do with front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

and look for the keyword 'COMMENT'. You can use that keyword to specify short comments on tables and columns (60 and 255 characters respectively)

Comment: Great. Thanks for that. Seems sybase [create table])(http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/19087) doesn't have this feature